# EJB module as a RESTful web service?

Tags: rest, module, ejb

can I use an EJB module as a RESTful web service?

There is previous questions asked on the topic such as the one below, but they are from a year to 3 years ago. "Why can't i create a RESTful web service in ejb module?"

Has there been any upgrades since then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now it's possible (leveraging CDI).

See the JavaEE tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkncy.html).

Comment: I want to explain what I am implementing and see which option you think is the right way to go. I am developing a REST web service which has access to a database through an entity manager. After a lot of research, the use of a stateless bean for multiple transactions is the preferred option. Is the CDI a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done.  Restful web services were initially described in the context of HTTP but I guess it is not limited to just that protocol. A good foundation knowledge of how the main HTTP operations are used would be good though.

So you will need the bean methods providing the service to follow fundamental rules.

The key things to note in the context of your implementation EJB module are:

Resources

(1) A resource is anything that has identity.

(2) Every resource has a URI.

(3) A URI is “opaque,” exposes no details of its implementation.

Resources are anything that can be used as "currency" for you service. If a client returns an object in a particular representation representing a dog from a particular method, they should be able to use that object to talk to other methods that may require something representing a dog. If that object representing a dog is to be used in multiple places then it has an identifier and a method for obtaining it. Method name + identifier = URI (unique resource identifier).

Protocol

(4)GET operations are “idempotent,” free of side effects.

(5) Any request that doesn’t have side effects should use GET.

(6) All interactions are stateless.

You may wish to implement bean methods in the form of getDog(Long dogID). Which is your URI for a dog of dogID identifier. All the methods with getXXXX() would have no side effects on the rest of the service. If only getXXX() were performed in on the service, the backend would not change one bit.

All interactions are stateless. So use nothing else but stateless beans.

Representations

(7) Data and metadata formats are documented.

(8) Data is available in multiple flavors.

(9) Representations include links to other resources.

So if that dog object which your client is using as "currency" has an owner referenced on it ( preferably this reference should be in the form of an identifier ie ownerID), the identifier can  be used to obtain the full owner representation using getOwner(ownerID), its URI.

Style

(10) Document and advertise your service API.

(11) Use available standards and technology.

(12) Refine and extend architecture, standards and tools

Make sure your method names are self describing and common throughout. i.e. updateDog(Dog dog) , create(Dog dog) , deleteDog(Long dogID). So if the client wants to create an owner they will instantly know what the method name is by the name of the resource 'Owner' and the identifier which in a previous example was obtained by a reference in the Dog representation.

Sorry for the long answer.

Comment: @M. Ogu: Thanks for the answer, could you elaborate more on points 7-12. I will be using JSON and XML. Also, I tried an example EJB module which exposed one method using the REST architecture. It deployed to Glassfish, but I was unable to access the resource over http.

Comment: If your services clients are other Java applications then you won't need to worry about JSON and XML. If your clients are anything else then you will need a web tier to provide the services instead. A web tier that includes servlet based infrastructure and a web.xml.